# Latitude-longitude mapping to Shapefiles

Tags: qgis

I have an EXCEL spreadsheet with a list of cities, province and Latitude and Longitude.
Example:
[image]

I also have a SHAPEFILES of Canadian Federal Election Ridings

I wish to update the EXCEL such that it would identify the Federal riding of the city based upon the Latitude-longitude coordinates
Example of update below.

[image]

I suspect that QGIS would have the algorithm to identify federal ridings

The EXCEL has over 30,000 locations.... so automation is a must.

---

I'm getting BLANK returns. See below
I'm getting:
Major city  latitude    longitude   FED_NUM NID FEDNUM  ENNAME.. .etc
but no mapping of a city to a Federal riding.

When I import the CITY EXCEL file and the Federal riding SHAPEFILE.. i can see the City dots over the various SHAPEFILEs... but it does not connect the City to the riding.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add your excel file via the [delimited text button](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html) (save it out of excel as csv). Drag your Ridings shapefiles into QGIS. You then want to do a [Spatial Join on the two layers](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html) and then save your new layer (by right clicking and picking `save as`), choose CSV as your output format and you can pull the file back into excel.

Comment: Hi Thanx for the lead. However, I'm getting BLANK returns. See below:Major city latitude longitude OBJECTID PR_HRUID ENG_LABEL FRE_LABEL PEER
Edmonton 53.54624 -113.49037     
Vancouver 49.26038 -123.11336     
Winnipeg 49.89953 -97.14113     
Fredericton 45.96063 -66.63911